# Program fails to load correctly

Tags: javascript

fello programmers!

I am working on a small little quiz game for my school (it's in german, but that's not going to matter all that much). I'm writing it in JavaScript, as that's the most the computers in our school manage to compile.

https://jsfiddle.net/rgc1ps6p/6/

```
    function ex1() {
  var f, h, g;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      f = "20"; //Entfernung
      h = "180"; //Geschwindigkeit
      g = "2"; //Beschleunigung
      sol1 = 45;
      break;
    case 2:
      f = "100";
      h = "108";
      g = "5";
      sol1 = 63;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Die Bösewichte sind auf der Flucht auf einer geraden Autobahn. Sie sind " + f + " Meter von dir entfernt und ihr fahrt mit einer konstanten Geschwindigkeit " + h + "km/h, wobei du dich stetig um " + g + " m/s² beschleunigst.";
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Wie lange brauchst du, um sie einzuholen?";
    document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="s";
  button.disabled = true;
  confirmation.disabled = false;
  input.disabled = false;
}
```

Here a fiddle of the site, it won't load the Script though. 
The given code is one of the functions used (as stackoverflow wouldn't let me post without some code).

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: What script isn't loading? Adding `alert(1);` to the JS shows an alert, so the JavaScript is loading.

Comment: Put your code below HTML, before closing body tag... Check fiddle, click to javascript button, to see selected option: https://jsfiddle.net/rgc1ps6p/7/ Also, check console, you will see errors... (before adding script to body, story wasn't defined)

Comment: Clicking the button below everything should modify the text inside the box (excuse me, didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: Script is placed at the body, check JAVASCRIPT button/link in fiddle, and check 'load type'... basically, problem was that your code was at the wrong place on the page...First, HTML should be loaded, then you can manipulate it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change JSFiddle's script load method.  In the JavaScript options (click on **JAVASCRIPT** in the upper right corner of the JavaScript pane) change **Load Type** to **`No wrap - in <body>`** and your code will work.

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rgc1ps6p/9/

It's specific to JSFiddle; if you copy your code and run it in a Stack Overflow snippet, you don't have that issue:

```js
var x, sol1, sol2, sol3;
x = 0;

function story() {
  x = x + 1;
  switch (x) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Willkommen zum Training, Rekrut! Der Spezialagent 700 braucht neue Helfer, und genau deswegen bist du hier!";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Da wir nur die Besten von euch auswählen, werden wir euch im Folgenden einem kleinen Test unterziehen, um eure Entscheidungsfindung aufgrund von euren Physikkenntnissen zu überprüfen.";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Es folgt die erste und die wohl leichteste der nächsten 3 Fragen. Beantworte sie möglichst schnell, denn je schneller du sie löst, desto wahrscheinlicher ist es, dass du aufgenommen wirst!";
      break;
    case 4:
      ex1();
      break;
    case 5:
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Die erste Aufgabe hast du bestanden. Gute Arbeit! Dir stehen noch 2 weitere Aufgaben bevor, die du zu überwinden hast.";
      break;
    case 6:
      ex2();
      break;
    case 7:
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Und die nächste Aufgabe mit Bravour bestanden! Noch eine weitere Aufgabe und du kannst dich schon als Helfer des Spezialagenten 700 sehen!";
      break;
    case 8:
      ex3();
      break;
    case 9:
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Die letzte Aufgabe auch bestanden, sehr schön! Dir steht noch einiges an Lernen bevor, bevor du mit 700 arbeiten kannst, aber du bist sehr nah dran! Hör nicht auf, zu lernen!";
  }
}

function ex1() {
  var f, h, g;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      f = "20"; //Entfernung
      h = "180"; //Geschwindigkeit
      g = "2"; //Beschleunigung
      sol1 = 45;
      break;
    case 2:
      f = "100";
      h = "108";
      g = "5";
      sol1 = 63;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Die Bösewichte sind auf der Flucht auf einer geraden Autobahn. Sie sind " + f + " Meter von dir entfernt und ihr fahrt mit einer konstanten Geschwindigkeit " + h + "km/h, wobei du dich stetig um " + g + " m/s² beschleunigst.";
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Wie lange brauchst du, um sie einzuholen?";
  document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "s";
  button.disabled = true;
  confirmation.disabled = false;
  input.disabled = false;
}

function ex1Sol() {
  var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (answer == sol1) {
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
    document.getElementById("confirmation").onclick = function() {
      ex2Sol();
    };
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      document.getElementById(answers[i]).innerHTML = "";
    }
    button.disabled = false;
    confirmation.disabled = true;
    input.disabled = true;
    story();
  } else {
    alert("Falsch!");
  }
}

function ex2() {
  var d, e;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      d = "300"; //Höhe des Hubschraubers
      e = "95"; //Höhe des Gebäudes
      rightAnswer = 64;
      break;
    case 2:
      d = "500";
      e = "50";
      rightAnswer = 95;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Du befindest dich auf einem Hubschrauber in der Höhe " + d + " Meter und musst einen Fallschirmsprung auf eine Plattform schaffen, die sich " + e + " Meter über dem Erdboden befindet. Um rechtzeitig die Kontrolle über den Flug zu erhalten, musst du 5 Meter über dem Ankunftsort den Fallschirm aufmachen. Um diese Regel einhalten zu können, ist es am besten, sich die für den Fall benötigte Zeit auszurechnen und beim Fall die Sekunden abzuzählen."
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Wie viel Zeit vergeht zwischen dem Absprung und dem Aufmachen des Fallschirms?";
  document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "s";
  button.disabled = true;
  confirmation.disabled = false;
  input.disabled = false;
}

function ex2Sol() {
  var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (answer == sol2) {
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
    document.getElementById("confirmation").onclick = function() {
      ex3Sol();
    };
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      document.getElementById(answers[i]).innerHTML = "";
    }
    button.disabled = false;
    confirmation.disabled = true;
    input.disabled = true;
    story();
  } else {
    alert("Falsch!");
  }
}

function ex3() {
  var a, b, c;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      a = "30"; //Geschwindigkeit des Bootes
      b = "10"; //Höhe des Stegs
      c = "20"; //Entfernung des Bootes
      rightAnswer = 439;
      break;
    case 2:
      a = "60";
      b = "20";
      c = "5";
      rightAnswer = 631;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Die Verfolgten setzen sich in ein Boot und fahren mit einer Geschwindigkeit " + a + "  m/s weg. Du bist ihnen auf dem Fersen mit deinem Motorrad und fährst auf das Ende eines Stegs zu, von dem aus du zu ihnen aufs Boot springen kannst. Der Steg liegt " + b + " Meter über dem Wasser, und zum Zeitpunkt deines Sprungs sind sie " + c + " Meter entfernt vom Ende des Stegs. Beachte: Das Boot  bewegt sich auch während deinem Flug.";
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Mit was für einer Geschwindigkeit musst du vom Steg abspringen, um auf dem Boot anzukommen?";
  document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "m/s";
  button.disabled = true;
  confirmation.disabled = false;
  input.disabled = false;
}

function ex3Sol() {
  var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (answer == sol3) {
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      document.getElementById(answers[i]).innerHTML = "";
    }
    confirmation.disabled = true;
    input.disabled = true;
    story();
  } else {
    alert("Falsch!");
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  height: auto;
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

#header {
  height: 30px;
  width: 698px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="box">
    <div id="header">
      <h3>Physik-Spiel zur Vertiefung der Grundlagen der Mechanik</h3>
    </div>
    <p id="text">
      Bitte den Knopf unten drücken, um das Spiel zu beginnen.
    </p>
    <p id="question"></p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="4" id="input" disabled>
  <pre id="unit"></pre>
  <button onClick="ex1Sol()" id="confirmation" disabled>Eingabe bestätigen</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="story();" id="button">Klicken zur Fortführung!</button>
  <script src="Physik_Spiel_Script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I see that it's working, but could you please explain me why that is? What difference does that make?

Comment: @MarkTheSmasher It's something with the various ways JSFiddle loads scripts. Someone else can probably explain it a lot better than I can, but it's a Fiddle-specific issue. I added your code as a Stack Overflow snippet in my answer -- click on the **Run code snippet** button and your code will work as intended, without having to change any settings.